# css.js. Анимация появления блока с изменением положения соседних элементов

Tags: javascript, css

Заставить блок (#visible) появится таким образом, чтобы он подвинул верхний блок с текстом в вверх, а нижний блок в низ и сам отрисовался аналогичным образом, то есть из своего центра вверх и вниз. Долго мучаюсь, не выходит.

```css
#oblast {
  width: 500px;
}

#one {

}

#visible {
  height: 300px;
  background: blue;
  display: none;
}
#two {

}
```

```html
<div id ="oblast">
<div id="one">Современный суперкомпьютер работает со скоростью 36,8 петафлоп в секунду, то есть примерно вдвое быстрее человеческого мозга. Такая производительность стала возможна благодаря использованию ИИ: он переписывает собственную программу, в первую очередь инструкции, повышающие его способность к усвоению знаний, решению задач и принятию решений. Одновременно он отлаживает код, отыскивает и исправляет ошибки — и измеряет собственный коэффициент интеллекта (IQ) с помощью тестов. На создание каждого нового варианта программы уходит всего несколько минут. Интеллект компьютера растёт экспоненциально по круто восходящей кривой. Дело в том, что за каждую итерацию ИИ повышает свой интеллект на 3%. Улучшение, достигнутое в каждой итерации, содержит и все предыдущие улучшения. В процессе развития Busy Child, как учёные назвали ИИ, был подключён к интернету и собрал не один развитие продолжается.</div>
<div id="visible"></div>
<div id="two">экзабайт данных (один экзабайт — это миллиард миллиардов символов), представляющих знания человечества из области мировой политики, математики, искусства и различных наук. Затем, предвидя скорый интеллектуальный взрыв, создатели ИИ отключили суперкомпьютер от интернета и других сетей, чтобы изолировать его от внешнего мира или другого компьютера. Вскоре, к радости учёных, терминал, на котором отображается работа ИИ, показал, что искусственный интеллект превзошёл интеллектуальный уровень человека — «универсальный человекоподобный интеллект» (УЧИ или по-английски Artificial General Intelligence — AGI). Ещё через некоторое время он стал умнее человека в десять раз, затем в сто. Всего за двое суток он становится в тысячу раз умнее любого человека, и его 
</div></div>
```

Comment: после какого события он должен появиться?

Comment: событие кастуется когда элемент который нужно вывести будет в центре, но с этим проблем нет. именно с анимацией затрудняюсь

Comment: Лично я не понимаю. Что значит `будет в центре`, кто его туда разместит и каким образом? С помощью чего управлять анимацией?

Comment: Хорошо, по клику на первый блок с тектом блок должен отобразиться. Это сделать я знаю как, но с эффектом анимации без понятий.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var visible = document.getElementById("visible");
var one = document.getElementById("one");
var two = document.getElementById("two");


one.addEventListener("click", show);

function show(){
visible.style.display = "block";
setTimeout(function(){
 visible.style.height = "300px";
 one.style.marginTop ="-150px";
},30);
}
```

```css
#oblast {
  width: 500px;
}

#one {
border: 1px solid;
position: relative;
transition: 1s;
}

#visible {
  height: 0px;
  background: blue;
  display: none;
  transition: 1s;
}
#two {

}
```

```html
 <div id ="oblast">
<div id="one">Современный суперкомпьютер работает со скоростью 36,8 петафлоп в секунду, то есть примерно вдвое быстрее человеческого мозга. Такая производительность стала возможна благодаря использованию ИИ: он переписывает собственную программу, в первую очередь инструкции, повышающие его способность к усвоению знаний, решению задач и принятию решений. Одновременно он отлаживает код, отыскивает и исправляет ошибки — и измеряет собственный коэффициент интеллекта (IQ) с помощью тестов. На создание каждого нового варианта программы уходит всего несколько минут. Интеллект компьютера растёт экспоненциально по круто восходящей кривой. Дело в том, что за каждую итерацию ИИ повышает свой интеллект на 3%. Улучшение, достигнутое в каждой итерации, содержит и все предыдущие улучшения. В процессе развития Busy Child, как учёные назвали ИИ, был подключён к интернету и собрал не один развитие продолжается.</div>
<div id="visible"></div>
<div id="two">экзабайт данных (один экзабайт — это миллиард миллиардов символов), представляющих знания человечества из области мировой политики, математики, искусства и различных наук. Затем, предвидя скорый интеллектуальный взрыв, создатели ИИ отключили суперкомпьютер от интернета и других сетей, чтобы изолировать его от внешнего мира или другого компьютера. Вскоре, к радости учёных, терминал, на котором отображается работа ИИ, показал, что искусственный интеллект превзошёл интеллектуальный уровень человека — «универсальный человекоподобный интеллект» (УЧИ или по-английски Artificial General Intelligence — AGI). Ещё через некоторое время он стал умнее человека в десять раз, затем в сто. Всего за двое суток он становится в тысячу раз умнее любого человека, и его 
</div></div>
```

Норм?

Comment: да, годно! Теперь адаптирую.

Comment: Дмытрык, не вкурсе почему в браузере Microsoft edge без функции setTimeout  код работает корректно, а в хроме ломается? Думал, эта функция нужна только для задержки.

Comment: Ответ нашел, это осоебенность свойства transition